# Scrapy - Replace downloaded image path with item url link

Tags: python, scrapy

As stated in the title, I am looking to replace the image path name with the item path name here is my example:

Running my scrapy, I get the files as the standard  SHA1 hash format.

If possible I would also appreciate if it can get the first image instead of the whole group.

URL name - https://www.antaira.com/products/10-100Mbps/LNX-500A
Expected image name - LNX-500A.jpg

Spider.py

```
from copyreg import clear_extension_cache
import scrapy
from ..items import AntairaItem


class ImageDownload(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ImageDownload'
    allowed_domains = ['antaira.com']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.antaira.com/products/10-100Mbps/LNX-500A',
    ]

        def parse_images(self, response):
        raw_image_urls = response.css('.image img ::attr(src)').getall()
        clean_image_urls = []
        for img_url in raw_image_urls:
            clean_image_urls.append(response.urljoin(img_url))
            yield {
                'image_urls' : clean_image_urls
            }
```

pipelines.py

```
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline
import json

class AntairaPipeline:
    def process_item(self, item, spider):

        # calling dumps to create json data.
        line = json.dumps(dict(item)) + "\n"
        self.file.write(line)
        return item
    
    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.file = open('result.json', 'w')
        
    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.file.close()


class customImagePipeline(ImagesPipeline):
        
    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
        #item-request.meta['item'] # Like this you can use all from the item, not just url
        #image_guid = request.meta.get('filename', '')
        image_guid = request.url.split('/')[-1]
        #image_direct = request.meta.get('directoryname', '')
        return 'full/%s.jpg' % (image_guid)

    #Name thumbnail version
    def thumb_path(self, request, thumb_id, response=None, info=None):
        image_guid = thumb_id + response.url.split('/')[-1]
        return 'thumbs/%s/%s.jpg' % (thumb_id, image_guid)

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        #return [Request(x, meta={'filename': item['image_name']})
        #    for x in item.get(self.image_urls_field, [])]\
        for image in item['images']:
            yield Request(image)
```

I understand there is a way to get the meta data, but I would like it to have the name of the item product if possible for the image, thank you.

EDIT -

Original File Name - 12f6537bd206cf58e86365ed6b7c1fb446c533b2.jpg

Required file name - "LNX_500A_01.jpg" - using the last part of the start_url path
if more than one if not than "LNX_500A.jpg"

Comment: can you provide and example of what the final filename would look like for your example?

Comment: I have updated the question with the original and the required file name

Comment: You can extract the product name from the URL, right?  A simple `.split('/')[-1]` will do that.  Given that, you can rename the file after it is downloaded, right?

Comment: @Tim That is true, but I get multiple images(generally 5) from the getall(), when I ran get() it was not outputting any image files and was making my spider run a lot longer than expected. I am new to scrapy and am not sure where i may have gone wrong there.

Edit - Would you suggest I do the .split('/')[-1] and add a function to iterate if found add a counting number?

Comment: Well, it's you who knows which images you want to keep.  Saving them with an incrementing number works, but then you lose the connection to the original HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it took a little tweaking but this is what I got. I extracted the name of the item and all of the images with `xpath` expressions, and then in the image pipeline I add the item name and the file numbers to the `requests` meta keyword `arg`.  Then add those two together in the `file_path` method of the pipeline.

You could just as easily split the `request url` and use that as the file name as well. Both approaches will do the trick.

Also for some reason I wasn't getting any images at all with the `css` selector so I switched it to an `xpath` expression.  If the `css` works for you then you can switch it back and it should still work.

**spider file**

```
import scrapy
from ..items import MyItem

class ImageDownload(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ImageDownload'
    allowed_domains = ['antaira.com']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.antaira.com/products/10-100Mbps/LNX-500A',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        item = MyItem()
        raw_image_urls = response.xpath('//div[@class="selectors"]/a/@href').getall()
        name = response.xpath("//h1[@class='product-name']/text()").get()
        filename = name.split(' ')[0].strip()
        urls = [response.urljoin(i) for i in raw_image_urls]
        item["name"] = filename
        item["image_urls"] = urls
        yield item
```

**items.py**

```
from scrapy import Item, Field

class MyItem(Item):
    name = Field()
    image_urls = Field()
    images = Field()
```

**pipelines.py**

```
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline

class ImagePipeline(ImagesPipeline):

    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None, *args, item=None):
        filename = request.meta["filename"].strip()
        number = request.meta["file_num"]
        return filename + "_" + str(number) + ".jpg"

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        name = item["name"]
        for i, url in enumerate(item["image_urls"]):
            meta = {"filename": name, "file_num": i}
            yield Request(url, meta=meta)
```

**settings.py**

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   'project.pipelines.ImagePipeline': 1,
}
IMAGES_STORE = 'image_dir'
IMAGES_URLS_FIELD = 'image_urls'
IMAGES_RESULT_FIELD = 'images'
```

With all of this and running `scrapy crawl ImageDownloads` it creates this directory:

```
Project
 | - image_dir
 |     | - LNX-500A_0.jpg
 |     | - LNX-500A_1.jpg
 |     | - LNX-500A_2.jpg
 |     | - LNX-500A_3.jpg
 |     | - LNX-500A_4.jpg  
 |
 | - project
       | - __init__.py
       | - items.py
       | - middlewares.py
       | - pipelines.py
       | - settings.py
       |
       | - spiders
             | - antaira.py
```

And these are the files that were created.

[LNX-500A_0.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxnA9.jpg)   [LNX-500A_1.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLDTt.jpg)   [LNX-500A_2.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P85bz.jpg)
[LNX-500A_3.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmJON.jpg)   [LNX-500A_4.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xng3.jpg)

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for the response, an issue I ran in and am not 100% if its on my side only. for the settings.py, should it be 'project.pipelines.ImagePipeline' or 'scrapy.pipelines.ImagePipeline' - because when i put in project/ my project name it comes back with an error response. - EDIT 2 - found my issue - had an additional folder for the pathing on my settings.py but i am still getting the sha1 format

Comment: The string should be the dotted path to the class that defines the ImagePipeline  so in my case it's at `project.pipelines.ImagePipeline`  because my project is literally called project, then it is in the pipelines file and the class is called `ImagePipeline` which is a subclass of the scrapy version....

Comment: o man, thanks for the further explanation. I found the pipeline issue. But I'm trying to debug the naming issue right now.

Comment: Oh sorry I just saw the edit... that is odd though. I literally copy and pasted it and im getting the same results every time

Comment: yea thats what i'm trying to figure out lol, i did the same and created a new project, might be my virtual machine. Your code does make sense and I think it should work as intended. Thank you once again for your help, you have been a lifesaver for me :D.

Comment: Make sure you delete you `__pycache__` folders... that could be tripping it up

Comment: I just went through it line by line again, and it all checks out.  If you have any other middlewares or pipelines activated then those might be messing with it.

Comment: okay, ill try creating a fresh project again and see what it comes back with.

Comment: So, I just ran it on a fresh project, and it worked seamlessly, it is most definitely coming from my middleware i think. Thank you again!

Comment: Hey @Alexander, question for you, how would I modify thumbnail names?
Example -

image_dir

- thumbs

--large

---[image-name].jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247460/discussion-between-shadobladez-and-alexander).